# Intersect Method encountering type mismatch #13 copying and pasting a row

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use the intersect method with worksheet change function.

VBA code for a particular worksheet:

```vb
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1:B10")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target = "XYZ pty ltd" or Target = "HXH Corporate" Then
            msgbox Target
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The code works when I copy and paste a new value in a cell within the target set.

An error prompt (#13 type mismatch) appears when I copy and paste a row (e.g. A1 through C1) of data over in the target sheet.

Comment: Target could be a range of multiple cells, so doing `Target = "..."` will not work. You could maybe use `Target.cells(1,1).value = "...."` Or something like `for each cell in Target` etc

Comment: Thank you so much - For Each Cell in Target and If Cell = "..." together work like a charm without any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**a)** `Intersect` is a function that gives all cells that are part of two ranges. It is often used to check if a specific cell is within a range (in your case B1:B10). The function returns `Nothing` if the ranges have no cell in common, and combined with the `Not`-operator, the If-statement will be true *if* they have cells in common.

**b)** Using `Target` as you do in `If Target = "XYZ pty ltd"` is a shortcut for `If Target.Value = "XYZ pty ltd"`. That means VBA will read the content of the cell and compare it against a string. This can fail for 2 reasons, both giving the runtime error 13: *(1)* When the range contains more that one cell (because `Target.Value` is now an array of values and in VBA, you can't compare an array with a single value in one go), and *(2)* if VBA cannot convert the content of a cell into a string - that's the case if a cell contains an Error (#NA, #NAME?...)

Your event routine gets `Target` as parameter, that is a Range containing all cells that where modified. You will need to loop over all cells individually:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Intersect(Target, Range("B1:B10")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim cell As Range
    ' Check only cells that are relevant
    For Each cell In Intersect(Target, Range("B1:B10"))
        If Not IsError(cell.Value) Then
            If Target = "XYZ pty ltd" Or Target = "HXH Corporate" Then
                ' ... (do your magic here)
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```